# Datatables stops working in IE8 because of odd characters

Tags: jquery, datatables, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am using Datatables to format a set of data on a simple site. It works great in every browser except IE8 which go figure is the one my client is using...

I have narrowed down the problem to this text `â€‹The Purveyors of Notgeld`

In my database I do not see the `â€‹` characters but in the browser they render. As I mentioned all other browsers are fine with it but IE8 cannot seem to handle it and blows up datatables.net

Using the Console in IE I get the following message.

```
HTML1114: Codepage us-ascii from (HTTP header) 
overrides conflicting codepage utf-8 from (META tag) 

page.aspx?QS=5c591a8916642e7367fd8591d421eeaf36dd166e4977c8c8e50039b489f39225
```

Comment: You should also send the "Accept-Charset" header, as you can see it sends the wrong charset and thus your characters are wrong. Also read: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)